# Appropriate cheese amount

Tags: dialogue, its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia

Why does Dennis say that “any amount of cheese before a date is too much cheese” in *It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what prompted that comment - he breathed on them, and they got the full force of the cheese!

So the context of the quote was not any cheese or a typical mild cheese, but a really strong one that stayed on his breath.   Any amount of THAT cheese is too much cheese before a first date!